# How do I change a separator in tabular just for one row in LaTeX?

Tags: latex, tabular, separator

I'd like to change a column separator just for one row in my tabular.

[image]

For now, the `=` is set up as a separator between columns, for  the last row I would like to change it for a `\vdots`.

Thanks a lot.

**EDIT:**

[image]

I did what @achim suggested and it works, but still is there any ''nicer'' solution?

Comment: how about merging the cells in the last row? Then you can just adjust the position of the ldots whereever you like, without the separator.

Comment: please post a minimal reproducible example. Then everyone has a chance to test ideas quickly.

Comment: A reproducible example is easier to pick by writing the code directly in the answer, see the modification is propose you !

Answer (score 1):

here is a proposition to use the align environment to align the equation you need and write all the math in one same environment rather than in a tabular.

It only require the package `amsmath` in the beginning of the file.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

Proposal
\begin{align*}
\text{vychozi tvar} & ~  & y' + p(x) y &= q(x) \\ \hline
\text{reseni} & ~  & y' + p(x)y &= q(x) / \cdot e^{\int p(x)\, \dx} \\
 & ~  & \left(y\cdot e^{\int p(x)\, \dx}\right) &=
 q(x) \cdot e^{\int p(x)\, \dx} / \text{integrace} \\
& ~  & y\cdot e^{\int p(x)\, \dx} &= \int q(x) \cdot e^{\int p(x)\, \dx}\, \dx \\
& ~  & ~ &\vdots  \\
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

The alignement is made with `&` sign and you can specify if it is `=` after or `\vdots`. You can still use text in this environment, juste use `\text{lorem ipsum}`.

This environment can number the line, juste remove `*` in `\begin{align*}`.

I tried to copy the bit of code you provided in picture, in future, include it in your question so we can solve issue quickly. Sorry if I made typos in my copy, I hope this suite your case.

EDIT : You may want to add the vertical line between the left text and your equations...here is a second solution, however I can't manage to align the equation all along

```
\begin{tabular}{l|l} 
vychozi tvar & \parbox{0.3\linewidth}{%
    \begin{align*} 
         y' + p(x) y &= q(x) \\ 
    \end{align*}}\\  \hline
reseni & \parbox{0.3\linewidth}{%
    \begin{align*} 
        y' + p(x)y = q(x) / \cdot e^{\int p(x)\, \dx} \\
    \end{align*}} \\ 
~ & \parbox{0.3\linewidth}{
    \begin{align*}
 \left(y\cdot e^{\int p(x)\, \dx}\right) &=
 q(x) \cdot e^{\int p(x)\, \dx} / \text{integrace} \\
y\cdot e^{\int p(x)\, \dx} &= \int q(x) \cdot e^{\int p(x)\, \dx}\, \dx \\
 ~ &\vdots & ~ \\
    \end{align*}} \\  
\end{tabular}
```